# What is the effect of the PS1 and LC_ALL-variables in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a .bashrc file with the following commands:

```
   PS1="..."
   export LC_ALL=...
```

What are these commands doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one [sets the way your prompt looks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) (see my own post on [pimping my prompt](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/intelligentcoloredprompt)). In the case of the example you gave, it will cause your hostname, followed by a colon, followed by the current path to appear in the prompt. The second one sets the default language/localization settings to use the POSIX C configuration, rather than whatever the settings previously were. I strongly recommend changing the value from "C" to some variation of "utf-8" depending on your language, in order to support Unicode. Ex:

```
export LANG=en_US.utf-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

PS1=.. Is setting the value of the prompt that is displayed

export LC_ALL is settiing an environment variable that will be available to programmes that bash executes. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html

Answer (score 1):

The first one, provided it's exported or otherwise propagated to the user's shell process, sets the format of the *command prompt*, i.e. the little text at the beginning of the line that reads your input. Check out the "PROMPTING" section in `man bash`.

The second line exports the `LC_ALL` variable with value `C`, which sets your *locale* (to the standard "C" locale). If you experience internationalization-related problems, this may need to be changed.